# ambiguous constructor call while object creation

Tags: c++, constructor

**My program is as follows:**

```
class xxx{
       public: explicit xxx(int v){cout<<"explicit constructor called"<<endl;}
               xxx(int v,int n=0){cout<<"default constructor called"<<endl;}
  };
  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
   xxx x1(20);    //should call the explicit constructor
   xxx x2(10,20); //should call the constructor with two variables
   return 0;
  }
```

When I compile I get the error:- **"call of overloaded âxxx(int)â is ambiguous"**

I know that compiler finds both *constructor signature equal* since I made an argument by default '0'.

Is there any way that compiler can treat the signatures different and the program would compile successfully?

Comment: Which one would *you* expect it to call and why?

Comment: The only thing I can see working for you is to to remove the default value of `n`. Note that you can still mark the second to be explicit.

Comment: ``xxx(int v,int n=0)`` is not a ``default`` constructor.

Comment: Was playing with explicit keyword. I know how to make it work, just wanted to know if there is any way to create the objects in this way.

Comment: What do you expect the explicit keyword to accomplish here?

Comment: @SantoshSahu explicit is to prevent implicit conversion when constructor takes one parameter

Answer (score 2):

You just need one constructor

```
class xxx
{
public:
    explicit xxx(int v, int n=0)
    {
       cout << "default constructor called" << endl;
    }
};
```

Then you could initialize XXX objects:

```
xxx x1(20);    //should call the explicit constructor
xxx x2(10,20); //should call the construct
```

Comment: Of course if the OP was planning on `{10, 20}` working, now it won't, but I'd take my chances on that.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 choices:

Remove one of the constructors:

```
class xxx
{
public:
    explicit xxx(int v, int n = 0); // don't forget explicit here
};
```

Remove the default parameter:

```
class xxx
{
public:
    explicit xxx(int v);
    xxx(int v,int n);
};
```

Either way the code in `main()` will work. The choice is yours (and is mostly a matter of a  subjective taste).

Comment: There is a difference: with just an `explicit` constructor, you can't convert implicitly from an initialiser list such as `{1,2}`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: sure, but there is no ``c++11`` tag in the question

Comment: No, but there's a C++ tag, and C++11 is the current C++ standard.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: de jure, but de facto most of the platforms lacks all of C++ 11 features.

Comment: De facto, [most popular platforms](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C%2B%2B0xCompilerSupport) support all or nearly all of C++11. I've been using many features (including initialiser lists) for more than a year, and I'm sure I'm not the only one who isn't stuck in the past.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: but you still need to specify -std=c++11 to compile the C++11 code. This means exactly that C++ and C++11 are two different entities (i hope it will remain so not for long).