# how waitpid() function is implemented in system() function in linux

Tags: c++, c, linux

I was going through Richard Stevens"Advanced Programming in UNIX Environment" and I found this topic.

***8.13. system Function**

*****Because system is implemented by calling fork, exec, and waitpid, there are three types of return values.**

**1. If either the fork fails or waitpid returns an error other than EINTR, system returns –1 with errno set to indicate the error.**

**2. If the exec fails, implying that the shell can't be executed, the return value is as if the shell had executed exit(127).**

**3. Otherwise, all three functions—fork, exec, and waitpid—succeed, and the return value from system is the termination status of the shell, in the format specified for waitpid.******

As of my understanding we **fork()** a process by the **cmdstring name** and **exec()** makes it separate from the parent process.

But unable to figure out how **waitpid() function** is a part of **system() function** call?

The below link [ambiguous constructor call while object creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356150/ambiguous-constructor-call-while-object-creation) didn't provide me correct answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After you `fork()` off, your original process continues immediately, i.e. `fork()` returns at once. At that point, the new process is still running. Since `system()` is supposed to be synchronous, i.e. must only return *after* the executed program finishes, the original program now needs to call `waitpid()` on the PID of the new process to wait for its termination.

In a picture:

```
   [main process]
         .
         .
         .
       fork()     [new process]
         A
        / \
       |   \
       |    \___  exec()
  waitpid()         .
      z             .
      z             . (running)
      z             .
      z           Done!
      z             |
      +----<----<---+
      |
      V
  (continue)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `system()` call would, in a Unix environment look something like this:

```
int system(const char *cmd)
{
   int pid = fork();
   if(!pid)  // We are in the child process. 
   {
       // Ok, so it's more complicated than this, it makes a new string with a
       // shell in it, etc. 
       exec(cmd);
       exit(127);  // exec failed, return 127. [exec doesn't return unless it failed!]
   }
   else
   {
       if (pid < 0)
       {
            return -1;   // Failed to fork!
       }
       int status;
       if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) > 0)
       {
           return status;
       }
   }
   return -1;
}
```

Please do note that this is SYMBOLICALLY what `system` does - it's a fair bit more complicated, because `waitpid` can give other values, and all sorts of other things that need checking.

Answer (score 1):

From the man pages:

system() executes a command specified in command by calling /bin/sh -c command, and returns **after the command has been completed**. During execution of the command, SIGCHLD will be blocked, and SIGINT and SIGQUIT will be ignored.

system() presumably uses `waitpid()` to wait until the shell command finishes.